# copying data from Sql Db in excel on basis of date and db taken from user

Tags: excel, vba

I am making some macro and taking datea and db from the user. and on that basis i am fetching the  data from db.
here is my code please take a look and share if any solution you have for this.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Function GetConnectionString() As String
Dim strCn As String
strCn = "Provider=sqloledb;"
strCn = strCn & "Data Source=" & Range("Server") & ";"
strCn = strCn & "Initial Catalog=" & Range("Database") & ";"
If (Range("UserID") <> "") Then
strCn = strCn & "User ID=" & Range("UserID") & ";"
strCn = strCn & "password=" & Range("Pass")
Else
   strCn = strCn & "Integrated Security = SSPI"
End If
    GetConnectionString = strCn
End Function
  Sub Test()
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Sql As String
Dim d As String
d = Range("A2").Value
d = Format(d, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    cn.ConnectionTimeout = 100
    cn.Open GetConnectionString()
    Sql = "select * from config where convert(date,logadate,103)='"& d &"'"
    ExecInsert (Sql)
        Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
        rs.Open Sql
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        **Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (rs)**
        cn.Close

End Sub

Sub ExecInsert(selectquery As String)
'End Sub

   Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
   cmd.CommandText = selectquery
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.Execute

End Sub
```

**Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (rs)** this is where i'm getting error

run type error '430' class does not support automation or does not support expected 
interface
i have all the dlls and registered them as well. and even no reference is missing from my end.

if any body have face this issue please help...

Comment: is it syntax error? check your white spaces cause it seems like there are too many

Comment: follow this: "SELECT * FROM [tblName] WHERE [Field]=Format(#" & dealdate & "#,'yyyy\/mm\/dd');"

Comment: thanks for responding,

Comment: still not able to solve.here is my code,Sub Button1_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim q As String
Dim d As String
d = Range("A2").Value
d = Format(dealdate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=[servername];Initial Catalog=[DBname];User ID=abcd;Password=abcd;Integrated Security=SSPI"
con.Open
q = "select a,b from [tblname] "
q = q & " where logdate=Format(# " & d & " #,'yyyy-MM-dd')"
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open q
Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset (rs)
End Sub

Comment: This is going to get very confusing, I suggest you ask a new question and clearly state what works and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a function called `Format` (MS Access and VB does).

In SQL Server you would use `Convert` (first verify that the SQL Server datatype is datetime, not varchar or char)

Or if your datepicker returns data in the correct format you can just add it straight in:

```
q = q & " where logdate='" & d & "'"
```

Be aware that if you have a time component you need to strip it out.

So...

1. Try the code above
2. Verify that the database is SQL Server and the datatype is DATETIME
3. Inspect the contents of your datepicker as a string and verify it's format

Comment: string d = range("A2").value

Comment: huh? Did you do the things I suggested?

Comment: yes that worked. perfectly. when i put the connection string in the code i mean con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hou150w8ahc5v1\sql01;Initial Catalog=sqlsss;User ID=CT\hmox;Password=abcd;Integrated Security=SSPI" then it worked. but in above problem i'm taking db name from user so that it can work on all db which user wants to perform the activity.

Comment: In your connection string you can remove `;User ID=CT\hmox;Password=abcd` as this has no effect - you are using integrated security. Do you still have an issue?I don't quite understand.